# ppa:webupd8team/java is only loading jre

Tags: java, react-native, java-8

The instructions at oracle state that running the following will install both the jre and jdk.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default`

and sure enough when I run `java -version` I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

and when I run `javac -version` I get:

```
javac 1.8.0_101
```

So I believe that means the jdk is installed. So to point $JAVA_HOME to the jdk I run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to see where to point to. I get:

```
  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_74/bin/java      1         manual mode
```

I don't see a jdk folder to point to here? I've searched for a `jdk` folder on the system (ubuntu 14.04) but don't find one. The contents of the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ folder are:

```
bin  COPYRIGHT  db  include  javafx-src.zip  jre  lib  LICENSE  man  README.html  release  src.zip  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
```

Am I going nuts or is the PPA repository not in fact installing the `jdk`?

The problem relates to a react-native application throwing this error `> Could not find tools.jar`

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who runs into issues with getting their local jdk install to work; one thing to check is that your `update-alternatives` has been correctly installed.

In my output above under `sudo update-alternatives --config java` you will see that the selected line points to the `jre` directory. I had been expecting to find a `jdk` folder to which I could point, but the jdk path (in this case) is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java`. With the oracle java-8 install the `java-8-oracle/bin/java` directory **IS** the `jdk` and the `jre` directory is a sub-directory of `java-8-oracle` (the jdk).

This was obvious once I downloaded `jdk1.8.0_101` only to find the contents were the same as `java-8-oracle`. In all my searches the advice was to point to the `jdk` folder - hence the expectation that something was missing, which it wasn't - just not named as expected.

To update your alternatives do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" \
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" 1  <-- should be your path; this is mine.
```